# How to tell which part of the stack trace is causing connection leak in WebLogc 8.1

Tags: connection, weblogic, memory-leaks, pool

i have a connection leak, which is captured by BEA WebLogic fortunately. However, after reading through some literature, i am still trying to find out which part of the stack trace may suggest which part of the codes i may be looking at.

```
        ####<May 21, 2011 1:16:06 PM EST> <Warning> <JDBC> <svrl003.sia.com> <svr3> <Finalizer> <<anonymous>> <> <BEA-001074> <A JDBC pool connection leak was detected. A connection leak occurs when a connection obtained from the pool was not closed explicitly by calling close() and then was disposed by the garbage collector and returned to the connection pool. The following stack trace at create shows where the leaked connection was created.  Stack trace at connection create:

        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection.init(PoolConnection.java:61)
        at weblogic.jdbc.pool.Driver.allocateConnection(Driver.java:254)
        at weblogic.jdbc.pool.Driver.connect(Driver.java:164)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver.getNonTxConnection(Driver.java:540)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver.connect(Driver.java:139)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:329)
        at com.oco.util.BEndOcDBConnectionPool.getConnection(BEndOcDBConnectionPool.java:188)
        at com.oco.util.BEndOcDBConnectionPool.getConnection(BEndOcDBConnectionPool.java:144)
        at com.oco.util.BEndConnectionManager.getConnection(BEndConnectionManager.java:38)
        at com.oco.ejb.confirmation.OrderConfirmationBean.saveConsents(OrderConfirmationBean.java:10213)
        at com.oco.ejb.confirmation.OrderConfirmationBean.saveConsents(OrderConfirmationBean.java:10172)
        at com.oco.ejb.confirmation.OrderConfirmation_9rmehc_EOImpl.saveConsents(OrderConfirmation_9rmehc_EOImpl.java:2178)
        at com.oco.ejb.confirmation.OrderConfirmation_9rmehc_EOImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:492)
        at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ReplicaAwareServerRef.invoke(ReplicaAwareServerRef.java:108)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:435)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:147)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:430)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicExecuteRequest.execute(BasicExecuteRequest.java:35)
        at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:224)
        at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:183)
    >
```

It seem to suggest that i should be looking at **com.oco.ejb.confirmation.OrderConfirmationBean.saveConsents**, however, can i be sure that it may be **com.oco.ejb.confirmation.OrderConfirmationBean.saveConsents** ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stacktrace always shows you what the current thread was doing at that point of time. So going through a stacktrace line-by-line is a pretty good line of investigation for your specific problem.

There are 5 operative lines in your stacktrace for you to understand - which I will run through.

```
at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:329)
```

This is the Weblogic Internal class representing the start of the call to get a connection from the pool, at which point Weblogic realizes none available due to a leak

```
at com.oco.util.BEndOcDBConnectionPool.getConnection(BEndOcDBConnectionPool.java:188)
at com.oco.util.BEndOcDBConnectionPool.getConnection(BEndOcDBConnectionPool.java:144)
at com.oco.util.BEndConnectionManager.getConnection(BEndConnectionManager.java:38)
```

These are 3 lines from your application code which is a ConnectionManager which fetches the connection. I guess this is centrally responsible for managing all JDBC connections in your app - so this is where you should be looking to see what went wrong.

```
at com.oco.ejb.confirmation.OrderConfirmationBean.saveConsents(OrderConfirmationBean.java:10213)
```

This specific line **no 10213 of the OrderConfirmationBean saveConsents** method is making the call to the `BEndConnectionManager` - this itself might not be the problem, what happens when it makes the call causes the problem.

So to recap, start at line no 10213 of the `OrderConfirmationBean` `saveConsents` and you see the BEndConnectionManager call might not be closing connections - now examine your code to **see if the closing connections is done or needs to be done** in `OrderConfirmationBean`  or by the `BEndConnectionManager`  itself.

**Update referring to BEA-001074**

I focussed more on the stacktrace than the BEA-001074.

So the BEA-001074 is a **Finalizer** message thrown when a Garbage Collector (GC) has run. So my understanding of what happens is:

Connection was used but not closed in the code, so some reference remains in the JVM heap of the Weblogic server. After a while, when the GC runs it realizes the connection is no longer active and runs the Finalizer just before garbage collecting it. BEA then throws the error `BEA-001074` to inform us that *a potential leak has been plugged* by destorying the reference and returning the connection to the pool.

To clarify your question, this does NOT seem to be at the time of fetching a new connection as my initial answer suggested.

Weblogic is able to **reproduce a stacktrace** referring to *the point at which the connection* (which should have been closed) *was actually opened*.

Some reading [on the Oracle forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=731577) shows that in some versions of 8.1 they are not able to reproduce the stacktrace, which shows a `Null exception passed`- so in your case it is good and working that you can see the actual stack.

Comment: Hi JoseK, just somewhere along the line of WebLogic BEA-001074 i don't understand. It seems that BEA-001074 suggests a connection pool leak, while the above stack trace and your explanation seem to suggest that an error occurred when trying to get a connection from an exhausted pool therefore raising BEA-001074. So does it mean WebLogic is raising a BEA-001074 in response to an exhausted pool? Sorry i am confused by this as this is the first time i am seeing this.

Comment: @Chin: I've corrected my explanation - the BEA 001074 represents a message at LATER point in time i.e. at GC time and not when trying to get the connection from pool.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you actually release your connections.  Make sure you use a finally block in the try/catch block to release the connection to catch exception scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid finalizers, see Bloch's book Effective Java. There is no guarantee when the finalizer will run thus you may be holding connections longer than you think resulting in a leak